# Reversing a queue, using only queues. Getting indexofbound exception

Tags: java, queue

```
public static Queue1 mirror(Queue1 s){
    int len = s.getSize();
    Queue1 ret = new Queue1(s.getSize());

    Queue1 tmp = new Queue1(s.getSize());

    while(ret.getSize()!=len){
        while(s.getSize()>1) tmp.insert(s.remove());
        ret.insert(s.remove());
        while(tmp.getSize()>1) s.insert(tmp.remove());
        ret.insert(tmp.remove());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

My implementation of insert and remove methods:

```
public void insert(int x){
    if(rear == maxsize-1) rear = -1;
    arr[++rear] =  x;

    count++;
}

public int remove(){
    int tmp = arr[front++];
    if(front==maxsize) front = 0;

    count--;
    return tmp;
}
```

The code does not work unless I increase the size of `Tmp` to `s.getSize()+2`, and in this case, it prints a zero.

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Which one of those snippets isn't working?  What would make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your loop is missing a couple of conditions.

Your problem is here :

```
while(ret.getSize()!=len){
    while(s.getSize()>1) tmp.insert(s.remove()); // 1
    ret.insert(s.remove()); // 2
    while(tmp.getSize()>1) s.insert(tmp.remove()); // 3
    ret.insert(tmp.remove()); // 4
}
```

Suppose your input is

```
s = [1 2 3]
```

After the first execution of 1 :

```
s = [3]
tmp = [1 2]
ret = []
```

After 2 :

```
s = []
tmp = [1 2]
ret = [3]
```

After 3 :

```
s = [1]
tmp = [2]
ret = [3]
```

after 4 :

```
s = [1]
tmp = []
ret = [3 2]
```

Then you repeat step 1, but it does nothing :

```
s = [1]
tmp []
ret = [3 2]
```

Then step 2 :

```
s = []
tmp = []
ret = [3 2 1]
```

Now you are done, but you still here to perform 3 and 4 before terminating. Step 3 will do nothing, but step 4 will give you an error, since you are attempting to remove an item from the empty queue `tmp`.

The solution is to add a couple of conditions :

```
while(ret.getSize()!=len){
    while(s.getSize()>1) tmp.insert(s.remove());
    if (s.getSize() > 0) ret.insert(s.remove());
    while(tmp.getSize()>1) s.insert(tmp.remove());
    if (tmp.getSize()>0) ret.insert(tmp.remove());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps. I wanted to find a solution myself to the problem: reversing a queue using only queues. Here is what I came up with:

```
public class Queue1 {
    private int maxSize, count, front, rear;
    private int[] arr;

    public Queue1(int maxSize) {
        arr = new int[maxSize];
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        count = 0;
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }

    public boolean insert(int x) {
        if (count == maxSize)
            return false;
        arr[rear] = x;
        rear = (rear + 1) % maxSize;
        count++;
        return true;
    }

    public int remove() throws Exception {
        if (count == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot remove from queue: it's empty!");
        }
        int ret = arr[front];
        front = (front + 1) % maxSize;
        count--;
        return ret;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return count;
    }

    public static Queue1 mirror(Queue1 q) throws Exception {
        int n = q.getSize();
        Queue1 ret = new Queue1(n);
        Queue1 tmp = new Queue1(n);
        boolean f = true;
        while (ret.getSize() < n) {
            if (f) {
                while (q.getSize() > 1)
                    tmp.insert(q.remove());
                ret.insert(q.remove());
            } else {
                while (tmp.getSize() > 1)
                    q.insert(tmp.remove());
                ret.insert(tmp.remove());
            }
            f = !f;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! This solution works. It iterates over all the queue and gets to the last element and saves it in the `ret` queue. It does this for all the elements.